# How to do horizontal split of the console in nodejs output

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

How can I keep doing `console.log` that scrolls, but keep one line at the bottom of the console to show the general progress, similar to the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use npm's [blessed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blessed) library to get to what I want. I uploaded a demo [here](https://gist.github.com/ourarash/5c3e8d9ea6dd6282f592a5b28c5a5836), however, it was rather slow.

Alternatively, I created another package called [log-with-statusbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-with-statusbar) that does the job but it is much more light weight.

[image]